# How to send just two integer values in one time to TCP Server from Android phone?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I'm working on an Android app with Java Server. I want sending two integer values to Java Server from my Android Client phone. I'm thinking something like array.

```
    value1=3; value2 = -5;
    dout= new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    byte [] a = {value1,value2};
    dout.write(a,0,a.length);
```

I've tried this on Java Server. But it's not working for me.

```
  DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
  int length = dIn.readInt();                    
  if(length>0) 
  {
  byte[] message = new byte[length];
  dIn.readFully(message, 0, message.length); 
  System.out.println(message);
  }
```

How can I read this on Server side? Or how can I send just two integer values to server in one time and reading at Server?

EDIT : I'm changed my codes with this.

```
        value1=3; value2 = -5;
         dout= new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
         dout.writeInt(value1);
         dout.writeInt(value2);

         dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        int value1 = dIn.readInt();  
         int value2 = dIn.readInt();
```

and I'm added "setTcpNoDelay(true)" for high latency. Now my codes is good working.

Comment: What's you got when you print your message?

Comment: I see this my Android side Log "[B@40567fb0" . And my Log ;  Log.w("Client",end-start+" : "+ a); "a" is my byte...

Comment: When you print an array it's it call its toString it don't print it's content.

Comment: You appear to cast your ints to bytes before writing them, but then try to read them as ints.  That probably won't work too well - by appearances your server will probably try to read 4 bytes for the first int, so it will get both values and whatever the next two bytes written are.  Binary client-server communication is tricky as the data types must match exactly - for that reason, a lot of protocols (http, etc) adopt the inefficiency but simplicity of communicating in printable text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many error in your code. First when you do :

```
int length = dIn.readInt();
```

It doesn't return the length of the array. It's return the first value you sent. In your case `length = 3`

Second erreor : we don't print an array like this:

```
System.out.println(array);
```

When you do like that you will get the array adress (not sure about this). If you want to print its content you should do a loop and print each element.

Why don't do like this :

```
value1=3; value2 = -5;
dout= new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dout.writeInt(value1);
dout.writeInt(value2);

DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
int value1 = dIn.readInt();  
int value2 = dIn.readInt();
```

Comment: It's working correctly. But I see more latency. (long start = System.currentTimeMillis();) 15-20 ms every time at Server side. Client side latency is 3 - 5 it's normal. Is this true way? are there any way about this send two int?

Comment: Sir, I'm added this setTcpNoDelay(true). and my latency is normal (3-5). So thank you for helping.